# Limit substitution

Tags: calculus, limits

When you have a one-sided limit, say $\displaystyle \ell = \lim_{x \to a^{-}}f(x)$, is there a substitution that I could perform to get $\displaystyle \ell=\lim_{x \to a^{+}}g(x)$?

Answer (score 6):

Let $y=2a-x$, then as $x \to a^-$, we have $y \to a^+$ and $g(x) = f(2a-x)$.

Comment: This is very nice, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use $g(x) = f(2a - x)$.

$l = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} g(x)$ means that for every $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$ there exists a $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $0 < a - x < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

The condition $0 < a - x < \delta$ is equivalent to the condition that $|x - a| < \delta$ (which is used in the normal, two-sided limit definition) and  $x < a$ (which comes from the left-sided limit, see the definitions for right- and left-sided limits [here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/OneSidedLimits.aspx)).

Likewise, $l = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^+} g(x)$ means that for every $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$ there exists a $\delta \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $0 < x - a < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

Setting $y = 2a - x$, we see that $y - a = a - x$, which implies that $g(x) = f(y)$. In particular, $0 < a - x < \delta \iff 0 < y - a < \delta$ (and vice versa), so if we have

$$l = \lim_{x \rightarrow a^-} f(x)$$
which means
$$ \forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+\ \exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}^+\ \text{s.t.}\ 0 < a - x < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$$
is equivalent to
$$ \forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}^+\ \exists\delta\in\mathbb{R}^+\ \text{s.t.}\ 0 < y - a < \delta \implies |g(y) - g(a)| < \epsilon$$
which in its turn is equivalent to
$$l = \lim_{y \rightarrow a^+} g(y)$$